# jquery, variable is undefined when the value has string characters

Tags: jquery

I am declaring a variable in jquery. The value is a part number from a data warehouse. It is always a string even though most of the time it is a string of numbers.  When the part id is all numbers like '4125052' there are no errors but if the first digit is a string like 'B4125052' then I get the error-- `Error: 'B4125052' is undefined. When I go to view/source on the outputted page I see the value as $itemid=B4125052; (no quotes).

```
    <%string id = Model.Part.Select(x => x.Id).FirstOrDefault().Trim(); %>
    <%int partsetupid = Model.PartSetUp.PartSetUpID; %>
    <%int numtoprint = Model.NumContinuationTCs; %>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
     $(this).ready(function () {
             var $theHtml = null;
             var $itemid=null;
             var $partsetupid=null;
             $itemid=<%=id%>;
             setupid=<%=partsetupid%>;
                theHtml = $("html").html()
             $.download('<%= Url.Action("TravelCardReport","Reports") %>', { filename_: $itemid, format: "pdf", numtoprint_:<%=numtoprint%>, html_: theHtml,partsetupid_:setupid }, "post");
             $('#Wrapper').hide();
         });
        </script>
```

Comment: You have almost answered your own question "[..] I see the value as $itemid=B4125052;(no quotes)."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
$itemid=<%=id%>;
```

to

```
$itemid="<%=id%>";
```

Comment: Thanks Znarkus that worked like a charm. I tried putting quotes around it but I was concatenating them not just placing quotes directly around the variable.